# What are the Netty Channel state transitions?

Tags: tcp, udp, netty, datagram, socketchannel

Netty channels have multiple states but I am unable to find any
documentation on the actual state transitions.  The closest to any
documentation on this that I could find for Netty 3.2.x system is
[here](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelEvent.html).

I was able to locate the possible states that a channel can be in
[here](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelState.html).

However there is nothing that describes the normal transitions that a
channel can make from one state to another.  It appears that not all
channels make all possible state transitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different Netty channels do indeed have different state transitions.

In general the possible state transitions for TCP based server
channels are:

```
OPEN -> ( BOUND -> UNBOUND )* -> CLOSE
```

If you are using a **SimpleChannelHandler** subclass in your pipeline
the equivalent methods for handling the upstream events when one of
these state changes occur are:

```
channelOpen
channelBound
channelUnbound
channelClose
```

Server channels *never* move into the **CONNECTED** state.

Server channels rarely move back into the **BOUND** state once they
move into the **UNBOUND** state, however this appears to be dependent
on the application so YMMV.

Note that server channels can fire events when a child channel is
opened or closed.  These events can occur only after the server
channel is in the **BOUND** state.  When these events are sent
upstream on behalf of the server channel then the following methods on
your **SimpleChannelHandler** subclass are called:

```
childChannelOpen
childChannelClosed
```

The possible state transitions for TCP based child and client channels
are:

```
OPEN -> ( BOUND -> ( CONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED )* -> UNBOUND )* -> CLOSE
```

It appears that moving into the **CONNECTED** state first is *not*
enforced within the channel code; however this state is invariably
fired first for both child and client channels within the Netty
framework before the channel is moved into the **CONNECTED** state.

If you are using **SimpleChannelHandler** or a subclass thereof in
your pipeline the equivalent methods are:

```
channelOpen
channelBound
channelConnected
channelDisconnected
channelUnbound
channelClose
```

A TCP based channel must be in the **CONNECTED** state before anything
can be read or written to the channel.  This includes server channels,
which can never be read from or written to, which is not much of a
surprise as server channels are invariably used only for managing the
connect operation on behalf of the server.

Datagram sockets operate differently than TCP based sockets in that
they can be used to read and write data without actually being
connected (though connecting a datagram socket can be faster as you
avoid security checks).  Datagram sockets can be effectively used
using both of the state transitions listed for TCP based child and
server channels described above.

Comment: good review, thanks, is it based on some tcp articles or just reading netty sources?

Comment: and a question: if I need to count active connection count that client does to remote peer, will it be enough to increment in `channelConnected` and decrement in `channelDisconnected`? Will the counter be exact in case of `keep-alive` connections and other features? Thanks!

Comment: I read the source for the details.  Figured I'd save someone else the bother in case they have similar questions.  WRT active connection count, it is indeed enough to increment your counter in `channelConnected` and decrement it in `channelDisconnected`.  The HTTP keep-alive and similar protocol-on-TCP constructs have no effect on Netty except indirectly as the application controls the socket connections.